# In-boxes and being pung

Tags: bug

People seem to be not getting pung by other peoples messages recently. I've seen several comments about it, and people I've pinged ain't been getting punged either. Also messages aren't getting into my inbox. Are the powers that be aware of the pinging crisis?

I've taken Dan Bron's advice and also asked on [Meta, here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259432/in-boxes-and-being-pung). If any users have had the same problem, perhaps you could add the details to the list in that question over there?

Comment: Yes, a new policy has been put in place that people who use the word "*pung*", aren't.

Comment: @DanBron Ah, but people who used to say "pinged" have been so frazzled by this bug that they've lost control of their past participles.

Comment: Ha! More seriously, I haven't noticed this problem on my end. What interface and device are you using? I'm using the iOS app on a phone. Are you using the full site in a browser? Which browser? And when you say "no pings", does that mean these people don't get any notification at all (no sound / badge / visual effect)? Do they still see the message if they happen to open their inbox, or is the message itself not appearing at all?

Comment: @DanBron I'm using the full site on both Firefox and IE on a PC. So far, F.E., StoneyB and I have all had problems with a) not getting messages left under our posts (either pinging or inbox), b) not getting messages which have been addressed to us either by being pinged, or in our inboxes. ? They just aren't appearing in inboxes at all sometimes.

Comment: Hmm, at first blush, sounds like a latency/client synchronization issue. But I'm really talking out of my read-end now. Since multiple people have experienced it, I'd recommend you collect together all their experiences and details and ask on [Meta.SE], where the devs and CMs are more active. Plus, if other people from other sub-stacks are experiencing the same issue, they can upvote you and weigh in with more details. PS: I suspect the reason you use words like *pung* is you use Internet Explorer. Rots the brain, you know.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, have asked over there. Will collect info from the others when I "see them."

Comment: Cool. I went over there and +1'd you.

Comment: @LittleEva Sure: /pʌŋd/!